# Visual Studio ASP.NET Dev server and IIS server

Tags: iis-7, authorization

I just configured my web application to use IIS rather than ASP.NET dev server and I am getting some weird behavior.

http://localhost:49584/Templates/UI/Img/featured_area_bg.gif
http://localhost/NopCommerceStore/Templates/UI/Img/featured_area_bg.gif

When I visit the first url, I the image, like it supposed to.

When I visit the second one, I get redirected to the login page. There is not config in the web.config that restricts any part of that path to a role or username. Even after I login when I get redirected, it still wont show.

Using Process Monitor, I was able to see the problems IIS is having. The result is shown below.

Path: F:\Development\Freelance\AWS\Store\NopCommerceStore\Templates\UI\Img\active_item.gif
Desired Access: Generic Read
Disposition:    Open
Options:    Sequential Access, No Buffering
Attributes: RE
ShareMode:  Read, Write, Delete
AllocationSize: n/a
Impersonating:  NT AUTHORITY\IUSR

Comment: post the images on a web service somewhere, not to localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are your authentication and authorization settings in web.config?

Try out following one.

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```